# calculated column in sharepoint list

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

I have requirement that to add auto-populated column in this format ” date_time_sequence no”. Here date will be selected by user in the form, time will be time of submitting and sequence no should be a no in 6 digits(ex:000001,000002) it should be incremented for every new request.
Please help out to do this…
Thanks & Regards,
Prasad Kommuru

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
CONCATENATE(TEXT([Column of Date],"DDMMYYYY"),"_",TEXT([Created],"HHMM"),"_",TEXT([ID],"000000"))
```

[image: Formula in Excel]

Comment: Will this not always add six zeroes before the ID, as opposed to having a total of six digits?

Comment: this will ave total of 6 digits. You can verify the formulae in excel by providing the dummy values

Comment: Yep - my formula gives 20130325000001 but Monica's also gives the time as was requested

Comment: check the image i have attached

Comment: For Sequence no, its not working. I want add sequence no as 000001 for first request, 000002 for second request, 000003 for third...like this final format is like (23072013_04:46_000001),(23072013_04:48_000002)...

Comment: You will not get running number ... you will have to use the current item ID as the sequence number.

Answer (score 0):

Something like:

```
=TEXT([Created],"yyyyMMdd")&TEXT([ID],"000000")
```